# FindInstance with a symbolic constant

Tags: parametric-functions, inequalities, findinstance

Please consider

`FindInstance[m >= 0 && x >= 0 && x <= m, {x}]`

for which, I would like a parametric answer `x = m` or `x=m/2`.
But this yields an error:

`FindInstance: The system contains a nonconstant expression m independent of variables {x}.`

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Perhaps `Reduce` is what you need?

Answer (score 1):

FindInstance wants to have all the variables listed expicitly. So you can do:

```
FindInstance[m >= 0 && x >= 0 && x <= m, {x, m}]
```

To see many answers:

```
FindInstance[m >= 0 && x >= 0 && x <= m, {x, m}, 5]
```

If you want a specific answer (like x==m/2), then you'll need to say that you want that form

```
FindInstance[m >= 0 && x >= 0 && x <= m && x == m/2, {x, m}, 5]
```

Thus FindInstance finds a numerical example, not a symbolic one. If you want to keep things symbolic, perhaps you can use Reduce or Solve, for example

```
Reduce[m >= 0 && x >= 0 && x <= m && x == m/2]
```

reduces to a smaller number of statements (two) that is equivalent to the four conditions input.